# getting data on database based on specific months using select

Tags: php, html-select

I want to get data from db and show it to my table but it only shows blank rows and the number of row entries no information at all?

```
 <form method="post" action="index.php">
<select name="month" id="month">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
```

I think the problem is here please help

```
   <?php

 $hostname="localhost";
  $username="root";
 $password="";
   $dbname="testproduct";


$db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);


$stmt = $db->stmt_init();

//
    if($stmt->prepare("SELECT fname,lname,checkin,checkout,rrate,reservefee,datepaid,modepayment,stats FROM tblguest WHERE MONTH(checkin)//checkin name of the row from database = ?")) {

    //
if(!$stmt->bind_param('s', $month)) {
    //if BIND fails, display an error
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $stmt->error);
}


$month = isset($_POST['month'])
      ? $db->real_escape_string($_POST['month'])//this 'month' is the select name
      : '';


if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $stmt->error);
}


 if(!$stmt->bind_result($fname,$lname,$checkin,$checkout,$rrate,$reservefee,$datepaid,$modepayment,$stats))//name of db rows and also the only information I want to show on the web {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $stmt->error);
}
```

done editing my table its working now but my edit button in which it should be pre-populated by data from data base is now showing blank textbox

```
 while($stmt->fetch()) {

    ?>

        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $lname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $checkin; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $checkout; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rrate; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $reservefee; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $datepaid; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $modepayment; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $stats; ?></td>
        <td align="center">
        <a id="<?php echo $fname.$lname ?>" class="edit-link" href="#" title="Edit">
        <img src="edit.png" width="20px" />
        </a></td>
        <td align="center"><a id="<?php echo $fname.$lname ?> "class="delete-link" href="#" title="Delete">
        <img src="delete.png" width="20px" />
        </a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php

}

}

    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>

</div>
```

edit_form.php tried echo $fname that textbox got an input of Notice:  Undefined variable: fname

```
  <?php
 include_once 'dbconfig.php';

  if($_GET['edit_id'])
{
  $id = $_GET['edit_id'];   
  $stmt=$db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblguest WHERE id=:id");
  $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));    
  $row=$stmt->fetch();
 }

 ?>
 <style type="text/css">
  #dis{
    display:none;
  }
  </style>




  <div id="dis">

  </div>


   <form method='post' id='emp-UpdateForm' action='#'>

     <table class='table table-bordered'>
     <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id; ?>' />
     <tr>
         <td>First Name</td>
         <td><input type='text' name='fname' class='form-control' value='<?        php echo $fname; ?>' required></td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
         <td>Last Name</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='lname' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $row['lname']; ?>' required></td>
     </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Contact Number</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='contactnum' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $row['contactnum']; ?>' required></td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='email' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $row['email']; ?>' required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Check In Date</td>
        <td><input type='date' name='checkin' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $row['checkin']; ?>' required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Check Out Date</td>
        <td><input type='date' name='checkout' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $row['checkout']; ?>' required></td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>Room Rate</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='rrate' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $row['rrate']; ?>' required /></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td>Reservation Fee</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='reservefee' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $row['reservefee']; ?>' required /></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;a.Date of Payment</td>
        <td><input type='date' name='datepaid' class='form-control'  value='<?php echo $row['datepaid']; ?>' required /></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;b.Mode of Payment</td>
        <td><select  name='modepayment' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $row['modepayment']; ?>'  required >
        <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="Bank Deposit">Bank Deposit</option> 
            </select></td>

    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td>Balance</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='balance' class='form-control'  value='<?php echo $row['balance']; ?>' required /></td>
    </tr> 

     <tr>
        <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;a.Date of Payment</td>
        <td><input type='date' name='balpayment' class='form-control'   value='<?php echo $row['balpayment']; ?>' required /></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;b.Mode of Payment</td>
        <td><select  name='balmodepay' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $row['balmodepay']; ?>' required >
        <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="Bank Deposit">Bank Deposit</option> 
            </select></td>

    </tr> 

     <tr>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td><select  name='stats' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $row['stats']; ?>' required >
        <option value="Reserved">Reserved</option>
            <option value="Check In">Check In</option>
            <option value="Check Out">Check Out</option>
            <option value="Canceled">Canceled</option>  
            <option value="Done">Done</option>
            </select></td>

    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-update" id="btn-update">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Save Updates
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I don't have any idea on what's happening now

update.php

```
    <?php
 require_once 'dbconfig.php';


if($_POST)
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $contactnum = $_POST['contactnum'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $checkin = $_POST['checkin'];
    $checkout = $_POST['checkout'];
    $rrate = $_POST['rrate'];
    $reservefee = $_POST['reservefee'];
    $datepaid = $_POST['datepaid'];
    $modepayment = $_POST['modepayment'];
    $balance = $_POST['balance'];
    $balpayment = $_POST['balpayment'];
    $balmodepay = $_POST['balmodepay'];
    $stats = $_POST['stats'];

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("UPDATE tblguest SET fname=:fn, lname=:ln, contactnum=:cn, email=:em, checkin=:ci, checkout=:co, rrate=:rr, reservefee=:rf, datepaid=:dp, modepayment=:mp, balance=:bl, balpayment=:bp, balmodepay=:bm, stats=:st  WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":fn", $fname);
    $stmt->bindParam(":ln", $lname);
    $stmt->bindParam(":cn", $contactnum);
    $stmt->bindParam(":em", $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(":ci", $checkin);
    $stmt->bindParam(":co", $checkout);
    $stmt->bindParam(":rr", $rrate);
    $stmt->bindParam(":rf", $reservefee);
    $stmt->bindParam(":dp", $datepaid);
    $stmt->bindParam(":mp", $modepayment);
    $stmt->bindParam(":bl", $balance);
    $stmt->bindParam(":bp", $balpayment);
    $stmt->bindParam(":bm", $balmodepay);
    $stmt->bindParam(":st", $stats);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);

    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        echo "Successfully updated";
    }
    else{
        echo "Query Problem";
    }
}

  ?>
```

Comment: what value `checkin` column store? 1-12 or `jan-dec` or `2016-11-11`(date) something like that?

Comment: If you're binding a parameter to the query don't escape it as well. Do one or the other (preferably binding), but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [get errors to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) because your code is probably giving you undefined offset warnings and you're not seeing them.

As you'll notice [from the mysqli_stmt::fetch() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php), this returns a boolean. You are then trying to use `$row`, which is a boolean as an array. Instead you need to use the variables you assigned previously in [mysqli_stmt::bind_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php):

```
if(!$stmt->bind_result($fname,$lname,$checkin,$checkout,$rrate,$reservefee,$datepaid,$modepayment,$stats)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $stmt->error);
}
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $lname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $checkin; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $checkout; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rrate; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $reservefee; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $datepaid; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $modepayment; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $stats; ?></td>
        <td align="center">
        <a id="<?php echo $fname." ".$lname; ?>" class="edit-link" href="#" title="Edit">
        <img src="edit.png" width="20px" />
        </a></td>
        <td align="center"><a id="<?php echo $fname." ".$lname; ?>" class="delete-link" href="#" title="Delete">
        <img src="delete.png" width="20px" />
        </a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
}
```